# Angular2 AOT ngtools/webpack failed on linux

Tags: linux, angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular2-aot

My project is building on Linux and I've no idea why.
The distribution is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0.

My environment is:

```
"node" : "6.9.1"
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.7",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.11",
"typescript": "2.0.10",
"webpack": "2.2.1",
```

When I build the application with ngtools/webpack with the following command:

```
rimraf dist && node --max_old_space_size=2048 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --profile --bail
```

It fails at the end of the compilation, but as we can see in the log, it generates the dist folder with the build. I guess there is something wrong at the end of the build...

```
 Version: webpack 2.2.1
    Time: 207558ms
                                                                         Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                fonts/custom-font-icons.ce13ab801013419a9435b06680f3adc1.woff?     7.3 kB          [emitted]
               fonts/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot?     166 kB          [emitted]
               fonts/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf?     166 kB          [emitted]
             fonts/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2?    77.2 kB          [emitted]
              fonts/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff?      98 kB          [emitted]
                              fonts/line.567f57385ea3dde2c9aec797d07850d2.gif?    13.1 kB          [emitted]
                           fonts/loading.8732a6660b528fadfaeb35bcf568875f.gif?    9.43 kB          [emitted]
                    fonts/password-meter.64ca45e5df0f0261431766d0701ac7b3.png?    1.56 kB          [emitted]
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot?    20.1 kB          [emitted]
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg?     109 kB          [emitted]
      fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf?    45.4 kB          [emitted]
     fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff?    23.4 kB          [emitted]
    fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2?      18 kB          [emitted]
          fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.9f916e330c478bbfa2a0dd6614042046.eot?    16.2 kB          [emitted]
          fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.3d3a53586bd78d1069ae4b89a3b9aa98.svg?      49 kB          [emitted]
          fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.38861cba61c66739c1452c3a71e39852.ttf?    32.7 kB          [emitted]
         fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.16e1d930cf13fb7a956372044b6d02d0.woff?    18.5 kB          [emitted]
        fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.7e367be02cd17a96d513ab74846bafb3.woff2?    14.6 kB          [emitted]
                    fonts/slider_handles.1868e2550c9853a938a6211d196f9dcd.png?    1.95 kB          [emitted]
               fonts/fontawesome-webfont.25a32416abee198dd821b0b17a198a8f.eot?    76.5 kB          [emitted]
                 fonts/custom-font-icons.be444f2f1d966a009c8230e2ca33d4ff.svg?    25.1 kB          [emitted]
                 fonts/custom-font-icons.58e12fc160fde110afe6126b2d7470cd.ttf?    7.22 kB          [emitted]
               fonts/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg?     444 kB          [emitted]  [big]
               fonts/custom-font-icons.01080eeb1f5d62cb71ee683f27e38d3b.woff2?    3.72 kB          [emitted]
               fonts/fontawesome-webfont.d7c639084f684d66a1bc66855d193ed8.svg?     392 kB          [emitted]  [big]
               fonts/fontawesome-webfont.1dc35d25e61d819a9c357074014867ab.ttf?     153 kB          [emitted]
              fonts/fontawesome-webfont.c8ddf1e5e5bf3682bc7bebf30f394148.woff?    90.4 kB          [emitted]
             fonts/fontawesome-webfont.e6cf7c6ec7c2d6f670ae9d762604cb0b.woff2?    71.9 kB          [emitted]
                                             js/vendor.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.js    1.76 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                                                js/app.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.js    3.41 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  app
                                          js/polyfills.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.js     119 kB       2  [emitted]         polyfills
                                           css/vendor.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.css     258 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                                              css/app.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.css     276 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  app
                                       css/vendor.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.css.map  112 bytes       0  [emitted]         vendor
                                          css/app.17428182d2aa7c61c2cd.css.map  109 bytes       1  [emitted]         app
                                                                    index.html  776 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                environment.js  521 bytes          [emitted]
                                                           img/ajax-loader.gif    2.05 kB          [emitted]
                                                              img/axa-logo.ico      71 kB          [emitted]
                                                               img/favicon.ico    5.43 kB          [emitted]
                                                              img/logo-axa.png    3.58 kB          [emitted]
                                                         img/selected-file.png    10.8 kB          [emitted]
                                                            img/user-photo.jpg    3.36 kB          [emitted]
                                                             service-worker.js   43 bytes          [emitted]
       [0] ./~/@angular/core/index.js 2.54 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:230ms building:3986ms = 4216ms
       [9] ./~/moment/moment.js 123 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:239ms building:6108ms = 6347ms
      [13] ./~/@angular/common/index.js 771 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:231ms building:3987ms = 4218ms
      [24] ./~/@angular/router/index.js 909 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:232ms building:4007ms = 4239ms
      [61] ./~/ng2-translate/index.js 1.81 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:196ms building:1566ms dependencies:5091ms = 6853ms
      [66] ./~/rxjs/Rx.js 9.58 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:208ms building:1611ms = 1819ms
     [146] ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js 635 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:227ms building:3996ms = 4223ms
     [211] ./~/@angular/http/index.js 734 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:232ms building:3998ms = 4230ms
     [346] ./~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:1611ms building:9565ms = 11176ms
     [556] ./~/@angularclass/hmr/dist/index.js 202 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:246ms building:6315ms = 6561ms
     [557] ./~/file-saver/FileSaver.js 5.96 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:240ms building:6340ms = 6580ms
     [558] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 258 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:4228ms building:19397ms = 23625ms
    [1631] ./config/polyfills.ts 357 bytes {2} [built]
            factory:39341ms building:147ms = 39488ms
    [1632] ./config/vendor.ts 782 bytes {0} [built]
            factory:39342ms building:159ms = 39501ms
    [1633] ./src/bootstrap/prod.bootstrap.ts 740 bytes {1} [built]
            factory:39342ms building:196ms dependencies:193ms = 39731ms
        + 1657 hidden modules

    ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_if.ngfactory.ts
    Module parse failed: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/fbranch-gui-webapp-axa/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_if.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (13:27)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | import * as import3 from '@angular/core/src/linker/view_utils';
    | export class Wrapper_NgIf {
    |   /*private*/ _eventHandler:Function;
    |   context:import0.NgIf;
    |   /*private*/ _changed:boolean;
     @ ./$$_gendir/src/bootstrap/prod.module.ngfactory.ts 300:0-108
     @ ./src/bootstrap/prod.bootstrap.ts

    ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.ngfactory.ts
    Module parse failed: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/fbranch-gui-webapp-axa/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (13:27)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | import * as import3 from '@angular/core/src/linker/view_utils';
    | export class Wrapper_NgClass {
    |   /*private*/ _eventHandler:Function;
    |   context:import0.NgClass;
    |   /*private*/ _changed:boolean;
     @ ./$$_gendir/~/ng2-bootstrap/alert/alert.component.ngfactory.ts 22:0-84
     @ ./$$_gendir/src/bootstrap/prod.module.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src/bootstrap/prod.bootstrap.ts

    ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ngfactory.ts
    Module parse failed: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/fbranch-gui-webapp-axa/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (13:27)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | import * as import3 from '@angular/core/src/linker/view_utils';
    | export class Wrapper_NgTemplateOutlet {
    |   /*private*/ _eventHandler:Function;
    |   context:import0.NgTemplateOutlet;
    |   /*private*/ _changed:boolean;
     @ ./$$_gendir/~/ng2-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.ngfactory.ts 23:0-94
     @ ./$$_gendir/src/bootstrap/prod.module.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src/bootstrap/prod.bootstrap.ts
```

If I run this on linux, I have no issue:

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.ngc.json
```

So I guess, there is something specific in webpack ngtools/loader, but I don't know what.

Here is the webpack.prod.config:

```
/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */

/**
 * Imports
 */
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');


/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
var ngToolsWebpack = require('@ngtools/webpack');

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = {

  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: {

    'polyfills': './config/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './config/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/bootstrap/prod.bootstrap.ts' // our angular app

  },

  resolve: {

    modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],

    alias: {
      'app': 'src/app',
      'common': 'src/common',
      'moment':'moment/moment.js',
      'jquery':'jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'file-saver':'file-saver/FileSaver.js',
    }

  },

  output: {

    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'

  },

  module: {

    rules: [
      /*{
       test: /\.ts$/,
       enforce: 'pre',
       loader: 'tslint-loader'
       },*/
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [ '@ngtools/webpack'],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      },

      // copy those assets to output
      {test: /\.png|\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf|\.eot|\.ico|\.svg$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'},


      // Support for *.json files.
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']})
      },
      {test: /\.css$/, include: helpers.root('src', 'app'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader'},

      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'], publicPath: '../'})
      },
      {test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, exclude: helpers.root('src', 'style'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'},

      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader'}

    ],

    noParse: [/.+zone\.js\/dist\/.+/, /.+angular2\/bundles\/.+/, /angular2-polyfills\.js/]

  },

  // Add additional plugins to the compiler.
  //
  // See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
  plugins: ( function() {

    var plugins = [];

    plugins.push(
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
      })
    );

    plugins.push(
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        //minimize: true,
        //debug: false,
        options: {
          ts : {
            'ignoreDiagnostics': [
              2403, // 2403 -> Subsequent variable declarations
              2300, // 2300 -> Duplicate identifier
              2374, // 2374 -> Duplicate number index signature
              2375, // 2375 -> Duplicate string index signature
              2502  // 2502 -> Referenced directly or indirectly
            ]
          },
          /*tslint: {
           emitErrors: false,
           failOnHint: false
           },*/
          postcss: [
            autoprefixer({
              browsers: ['last 2 version']
            })
          ]
        }
      })
    );
    // plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());

    plugins.push(
      // Adding jQuery
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        "window.jQuery": 'jquery'
      })
    );

    plugins.push(
      // Adding Moment
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        moment: 'moment'
      })
    );

    plugins.push(
      // Adding Moment
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        moment: 'file-saver'
      })
    );

    plugins.push(
      // Inject script and link tags into html files
      // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/public/index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      })
    );

    plugins.push(
      // Extract css files
      // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
      new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].[hash].css')
    );

    plugins.push(
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        },
        output: {
          comments: false
        },
        sourceMap: false
      }));

    plugins.push(
      // Copy assets from the public folder
      // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: helpers.root('src/public')
      }])
    );

    plugins.push(
      new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: '[path].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: /\.js$|\.css$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
      })
    );

    plugins.push(new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
      entryModule: helpers.root('src/bootstrap/prod.module#ProdModule'),
      tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.aot.json',
    }));

    return plugins;

  }())

};
```

And here is the tsconfig.ngc:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mapRoot": "",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "lib",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./app/ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "./src/bootstrap/prod.module#ProdModule",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/bootstrap/dev.bootstrap.ts",
    "src/bootstrap/dev.module.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Any idea how could I have more info to make it work on linux?

Comment: Thanks for the "unvote" ... but could you explain me at least why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this post:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3674

I've finally found the issue.
The mainPath was missing in the AotPlugin:

```
mainPath: root('src', 'bootstrap.ts')
```

And there was also a typo in the webpack.config:

```
exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))$/]
```

The last $ was missing...